Error reporting for using input parameters of external functions in nested functions (python)
I define two functions like the following:
def is_even(x): # Even numbers have remainder 0 when divided by 2.
    return x % 2 == 0

def make_keeper(n):
    def func1(cond):
        while n >= 1:
            if cond(n):
                print(n) 
            n -= 1
        return None

    return func1

and I call it :
make_keeper(5)(is_even)

but it raises an error:
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[72], line 1
----> 1 make_keeper(5)(is_even)

Cell In[71], line 3, in make_keeper.<locals>.func1(cond)
      2 def func1(cond):
----> 3     while n >= 1:
      4         if cond(n):
      5             print(n) 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

since the parent frame of func1 is make_keeper(), why I can not use the input parameter of make_keeper in func1?
I also tried another method, using for loop instead of while loop:
def make_keeper(n):
    def func1(cond):
        print(n)
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            if cond(i):
                print(i)

    return func1

and call it:
make_keeper(5)(is_even)

it returns:
5
2
4

I'm now confusing why the first method raise an error?

The difference is you don't assign to n in the second example.
